# Why does GNU sed print output when using the -n option with the a command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, gnu

I came across some unexpected behavior when using the `sed` command with the `-n` option and the `a` command. According to the `sed` manual, the `-n` option should suppress automatic printing of the pattern space at the end of each cycle through the script. However, when I run the following command:

```
echo a | sed -n -e ‘$a b’
```

It prints `b`, even though I would expect it to print nothing.

I tried running the command `echo a | sed -n -e '$a b'`, expecting it to print nothing because of the `-n` option. However, it printed `b`, which was unexpected. If this is the expected behavior of GNU `sed` when using these options together, it means that I am misunderstanding how they should work. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: According to the [POSIX standard for `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03), the `a` command will "Write text to standard output as described previously." So it's not considered "automatic printing", it's printing explicitly directed by a command (which `-n` does not suppress).

Comment: Indeed.  `a` _does not change the pattern space_.  It just causes lines to be printed.  If you wanted to change the pattern space, you would have used a substitution: `$s/$/\nb/`.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle) helps. N.B. The `i`,`a`,`c` and `=` output to stdout and are not part of the pattern space. Also `a appended text` is gnu specific where as `a\appened text` is posix. Finally `F` is gnu specific outputs the filename or `-` if piped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Diego's excellent answer a bit, the `-n` options basically says "shut up unless I ask for something", but if it totally suppressed ALL output, it would be useless, yes?

Basically, any time you *tell* `sed` you want output, it will still give it.

```
$: cat file
<this is the content of "file">
$: printf "%s\n" {a..z} | sed -n '
2=           # the line number
3p           # print this line
4l           # "list" unambiguously
5r file
/f/a oo      # add - still hides f
/m/i hi      # insert - still hides m
/q/c silent! # change - new value shows
' # note a i and c include the comment.
2
c
d$
<this is the content of "file">
oo      # add - still hides f
hi      # insert - still hides m
silent! # change - new value shows
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you and Diego for your responses. The documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html) states that the `-n` option should cause `sed` to only produce output when explicitly told to via the `p` command. I have sent an email to bug-sed@gnu.org to report this possible issue. Thank you again for your help in understanding this behavior.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, the wording is misleading, and kudos for pointing it out and reporting it. *Always test!*

Answer (score 4):

```
echo a | sed -n -e ‘$a b’
```

prints

```
b
```

and

```
echo a | sed -e ‘$a b’
```

prints

```
a
b
```

which shows that when `-n` is specified the content of the *pattern space* is not printed.